# Maven is not detecting ArangoDB 2.8.6 java driver

Tags: eclipse, maven, arangodb

I'm trying to create Maven Project in eclipse for my java application with ArangoDB 2.8.6 version. But unfortunately my Maven Project is throwing the below error after my pom.xml entry:

> "Missing artifact com.arangodb:arangodb-java-driver:jar: 2.8.6"

My entry in pom.xml is as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

When i try giving version 2.4 in pom.xml its working with out any issues. But i would like to work on 2.8.6 version.

Please help how to proceed further.

Also saw Arango DB Java Driver in github: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver

How to bundle this to my Maven project.

Please help.

Comment: I am not sure if it this artifact is there in central repo. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.arangodb/arangodb-java-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up the versions. The latest available version of the driver is 2.7.4 (or 2.7.5-SNAPSHOT if you prefer snapshots), even in the GitHub link you have provided.

However, the ArangoDB version supported includes ArangoDB 2.8.x so even with the 2.7.4 driver you should be able to use ArangoDB 2.8.6, which I suspect is what you want.

EDIT: To clarify, you should simply be able to use the 2.7.4 version of the driver in your dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel...Yes the driver version is 2.7.4 but it is able to support version 2.8.6 as well. Just checked and it is working. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the file is not there in central repo but you like to work with it. Follow the below steps:

1. Download the project from `git` and build locally and get the project jar file.
2. Install the jar in your local repo using below command:

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`
3. Mention the version and artifact in your project pom file.

Comment: Hi Helios..thanks for your response. I'll try building it locally and see.